# Attempting to request spotify user authentication gives 401 no token provided

Tags: httprequest, spotify, ktor

I'm attempting to get user authentication for the spotify api following [the authorization code flow example](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/). Heres the URL of my request (with my client ID replaced with `CLIENTID`):

```
https://api.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin%2Fcallback
```

The URL is a redirect of the `/login/` route on my ktor server. Here is the code for the route.

```
get("/login") {
    call.respondRedirect {
        protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
        host = "api.spotify.com"
        encodedPath = "/authorize"
        parameters.apply {
            append("response_type", "code")
            append("client_id", Settings.CLIENT_ID)
            append("redirect_uri", Settings.REDIRECT_URI)
        }
    }
}
```

The code should redirect first to the spotify authorization page, where users will sign in and authorize my app. Then, it will redirect back to `localhost:8080/login/callback`, with the auth code and state or the error and state.

Instead, I keep getting an error about not having a token.

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

I tried adding my application secret under the `token` parameter and different redirect_uris (my IP address and sites like youtube.com or google.com instead of localhost).
Whenever I tried a different redirect URI I also added it on the app settings in my dashboard. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please try using the `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize` URL instead of `https://api.spotify.com/authorize`? See the example at https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/#request-user-authorization

Comment: @AlekseiTirman this worked, thanks! can't believe I didn't catch that.